# Julia string concatenation gives an array that elements are broken to individual characters

Tags: julia

I hope I get someone who understand this. I have been trying to concatenate Julia string for quit a while now but I still have an issue. I have this loop where I am trying to concatenate the string and a number from the loop then add the new value to an array, everything is fine when I print the value in the  loop but printing the arrays then all the elements of the array are split again to individual characters.
my code is as bellow

```
a = 1
for i in nums_loop
    i_val = i[a]
    append!(const_names, (string(x,  string(a))))
    println(string(x,  string(a)))
    a += 1
end
print(const_names)
```

the output is as bellow

```
X1
X2
Any['X', '1', 'X', '2']
```

Comment: Post code here, not in some 3rd part link. Describe what's wrong with this code, what's the output and how is it different from your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems the easiest way: first initiliaze your array_names with an empty string, later removing it with `popfirst!` (bad practise to call the array constant if you are actually changing its content)

```
array_names=[" "]
num_loops=2

for i=1:num_loops
    push!(array_names, "X$i")
end
popfirst!(array_names)
println(array_names)
```

This gives me the result:

```
julia> println(array_names)
["X1", "X2"]
```

Comment: I have a pre-defined empty array called const_names which I did not include in the code I pasted, so I am appending to the array but when I print the array the elements I appended are broken to individual characters. I don't need to concatenate the array but I need to make a string by concatenating two strings then appends it to the array,.

Comment: hey @kim I've updated my answer now, this should work